# Why does apache2 not show on tcp4 ports although it is listening on both tcp4 and tcp6 ports by default?

Tags: 20.04, apache2, tcp-ip

Why does `apache2` not show on tcp4 ports although apache2 is listening on both tcp4 and tcp6 ports by default ?

```bash
$ alias nocomment
alias nocomment='egrep -v "^(\s*#|$)"'
$ nocomment /etc/apache2/ports.conf
Listen 80
Listen 443
$ sudo ss -4ntlp | column -t | grep apache2
$ sudo ss -6ntlp | column -t | grep apache2
LISTEN  0       511     *:80        *:*           users:(("apache2",pid=23093,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23081,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23080,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23070,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23053,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23039,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23038,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23037,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23036,fd=4),("apache2",pid=23035,fd=4),("apache2",pid=4984,fd=4))
LISTEN  0       511     *:443       *:*           users:(("apache2",pid=23093,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23081,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23080,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23070,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23053,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23039,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23038,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23037,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23036,fd=6),("apache2",pid=23035,fd=6),("apache2",pid=4984,fd=6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache2 is listening for IPv4 requests and IPv6 requests on the same TCP(*with IPv6 ... AKA tcp6*) socket ... Handling IPv4 connections with an IPv6 socket using [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=addresses-ipv4-mapped-ipv6) ... This is supposed to be a performance feature that is enabled by default on [many Operating systems](https://apache2.com/2.2.2/bind.html) including Ubuntu.